# sqlite3 query by max and filter by second factor

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have:

```
TABLE MESSAGES
 message_id | conversation_id | from_user | timestamp  |  message
```

I want:

```
1. SELECT * WHERE from_user <> id 
2. GROUP BY conversation_id
3. SELECT in every group row with MAX(timestamp) **(if there are two same timestamps in a group use second factor as highest message_id)** !!!
4. then results SORT BY timestamp
```

to have result:

```
2|145|xxx|10000|message

6|1743|yyy|999|message

7|14|bbb|899|message
```

with eliminated

```
1|145|xxx|10000|message    <- has same timestamp(10000) as message(2) belongs to the same conversation(145) but message id is lowest  

5|1743|me|1200|message <- has message_from == me
```

example group with same timestamp

[image]

i want from this group row 3 but i get row 2 from query

```
SELECT max(message_timestamp), message_id, message_text, message_conversationId
FROM MESSAGES
WHERE message_from <> 'me'
GROUP BY message_conversationId
ORDER by message_Timestamp DESC
```

what is on my mind to do union from message_id & timestamp and then get max???

Comment: Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data

Comment: Voted to migrate this to DBA.SE (because it has been cross-posted there: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116123/query-with-max-and-second-factor ), so they can be merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below sql to achieve your purpose by group by twice.

```
select m.*
from
Messages m
-- 3. and then joining to get wanted output columns
inner join
(
    --2. then selecting from this max timestamp - and removing duplicates
    select conversation_id, max(timestamp), message_id
    from
    (
        -- 1. first select max message_id in remainings after the removal of duplicates from mix of cv_id & timestamp
        select conversation_id, timestamp, max(message_id) message_id
        from Messages
        where message <> 'me'
        group by conversation_id, timestamp
    ) max_mid
    group by conversation_id
) max_mid_ts on max_mid_ts.message_id = m.message_id
order by m.message_id;
```

http://goo.gl/MyZjyU

Comment: yes it works but how it's different from mine approach ? i create new column and i get max on it ( ok i maybe understand 10 + 100 != 101 + 00 but those two are 10100 )

Comment: thanks i mange to insert where clausule  :) and set order by .. but im trying to understand your query

Comment: if you adding of these field like string, the problem is that 10||20 > 10||101 => '1020' > '10101', it finally chooses the lower message id.

Comment: 1. first you select max message_id in remainings after the removal of duplicates from mix of cv_id & timestamp

Comment: 2. then u selecting from this max timestamp - and removing duplicates

Comment: 3. and then you joining - and im lost - to much of actions at once :d

Comment: thanks  for your help - when I'll have other problems in my project i'll know who to look for

Comment: Have ever think adding two long columns like max(10+20, 10+101) => max(30, 111) instead of adding them like string. I just try that, actually it **does not work**  as it cannot have the meaning of considering **max of one column then another column**. I just think of that and remind you. Try this and see the difference http://goo.gl/B9dcE8

Comment: sorry timestamp is as **datetime** in  table definition - maybe this is why it is working - see my edit2 on answer

Comment: maybe its because message id's and timestamps are growing relatievely

Comment: order of insertion - message ids are growing with timestamp  so u can add them and treat like enhanced timestamp

Comment: edit2 works because the timestamp is a relative large number but the request id is small. But when the request id growing and larger the timestamp, then it wound have problem that it get max of request id then timestamp. you better prevent this as edit2 is conditionally "true", and programmatically incorrect,

Comment: and how to add to this query second left join ( we grouping by conversation_id - this group containing user_from me & secon one ) when we selecting on <> me i now who i lose - but when i select lat row lost info who was second side of conversation and i want to add this info to other query

Comment: Sorry, I can't get your meaning. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: what do u think @daniel about ypercube answer http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116123/query-with-max-and-second-factor/#answer-116139

Comment: the solution is correct and result the same output as this answer. but i can see the answer has sub query, therefore the performance is not promised for large table.

Comment: i have tried to understand what you want from http://goo.gl/Dk9q53, but i guess some logic wrong in it, i try to rewrite it in main.sql of http://goo.gl/icKM7G. As the logic become more complicated, it is harder to get better sql. I just try to prevent sub query in the sql.

Comment: no not that @daniel - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872968/sqlite-query-with-second-joining but your hints as always are very precious

Comment: you want to select the "second last" user message row (which "second last" is different to the already got last user of the conversation) linear to the last row of the conversation, right?

Comment: yes i used "left" join for that(at the end of first one)  - but i decided to rewrite table to hold this information to not query for it

Answer (score 2):

Your query is based on non-standard use of `GROUP BY` (I think SQLite allows that only for compatibility with MySQL) and I'm not at all sure that it will produce determinate results all the time.

Plus it uses `MAX()` on concatenated columns. Unless you somehow ensure that the two (concatenated) columns have fixed widths, the results will not be accurate for that reason as well.

I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT 
    m.message_timestamp, 
    m.message_id, 
    m.message_text,
    m.message_conversationId
FROM 
    ( SELECT message_conversationId         -- for every conversation
      FROM messages as m
      WHERE message_from <> 'me'            
      GROUP BY message_conversationId
    ) AS mc
  JOIN 
    messages AS m                           -- join to the messages
      ON  m.message_id =        
          ( SELECT mi.message_id            -- and find one message id
            FROM messages AS mi
            WHERE mi.message_conversationId      -- for that conversation
                  = mc.message_conversationId
              AND mi.message_from <> 'me'
            ORDER BY mi.message_timestamp DESC,  -- according to the
                     mi.message_id DESC          -- specified order
            LIMIT 1                              -- (this is the one part)
          ) ;
```

Comment: thanks @ypercube for help !!! group by in my case  is used with agregation (max) - u dont use any agregation on "mc" .. what do u mean by " I'm not at all sure that it will produce determinate results all the time." i see u use limit & order & joining - daniel uses max & joining  - u use different type of write the query ""JOIN name AS  ON  var  = SELECT "  daniel in his example "JOIN ( SELECT ) AS name = "   for me it's makes more dificulties to read query if u use some magic ON AS JOIN  .. etc   where is the beginning and where is the end  :)

Comment: I see more graphically - as cut /create/split/merge tables :D - 
So it would be nice to see some graphical interpretation such a complex query :)

Comment: Your query has `GROUP BY message_conversationId` and at the same time `SELECT max(message_timestamp), message_id, message_text`. If there are many rows with same `conversationId`, the maximum timestamp will be returned. That's fine. But which of all the `message_id` will be returned? which of all the `message_text`? You assume that it will be the ones with the max timestamp but I'm not sure at all it will be that way. It may be a different message_id (not the latest) and a different text.

Comment: Yes, the `message_from <> 'me'` is needed twice.

Comment: but with or without i got the same results for 5000 rows

Comment: I suppose all the 5000 conversations have messages by other users (besides `'me'`). Do you want a conversation to be included in the results if hasn't?

Comment: see my second question @ypercube - i want to create a couple of queries eg for received conversation, all conversation, conversation for selected message_from etc  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872968/sqlite-query-with-second-joining

Answer (score 0):

ok it was more simple than I thought:

basically to change select from:

```
max(message_timestamp)
```

to:

```
max(message_timestamp || message_id)   
or  max(message_timestamp + message_id)
```

so it will **search for max  on concatenation** of timestamp and message_id

ps. after a digging - it's working only if message id is growing with timestamp ( order of insertion is preserved )

edit:

[image]

edit2 :

so why it works ?

[image]

```
SELECT max(message_timestamp+message_id), message_timestamp, message_id, message_conversationId, message_from,message_text
FROM MESSAGES
WHERE message_conversationId = 1521521
AND message_from <> 'me'
ORDER by message_Timestamp DESC
```

[image]

Comment: String comparisons on timestamps might be wrong (`10` < `9`).

Comment: select '20' > '100' returns true, so concatenation not works unless you ca make sure the length after convert into string without length difference of the two column.

Comment: yes but i got timestamp as long and message_id as long so how about add both values

Comment: edit2 works because the timestamp is a relative large number but the request id is small. But when the request id growing and larger the timestamp, then it wound have problem that it get max of request id then timestamp. you better prevent this as edit2 is conditionally "true", and programmatically incorrect.

Comment: although request id larger than timestamp rarely happen as the table rarely such big

Comment: The concatenation will only work if the two columns have fixed width size (in number of characters). Message_id `10000` will sort after message_id `9999`, so you'll get wrong results in that and similar cases.