# query with max and second factor

Tags: sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have:

```
MESSAGES table
message_id | conversation_id | from_user | timestamp  |  message
```

I want:

1. `SELECT * WHERE from_user <> id`
2. `GROUP BY conversation_id`
3. `SELECT` in every group the row with `MAX(timestamp)` - if there are equal timestamps in a group, use second factor as highest `message_id`
4. then sort the results `ORDER BY timestamp`

to have result:

```
2|145|xxx|10000|message
6|1743|yyy|999|message
7|14|bbb|899|message
```

with eliminated

```
1|145|xxx|10000|message 
    (has the same timestamp(10000) as message(2) of the same conversation(145) 
    but message id is lowest)  
5|1743|me|1200|message 
    (has `message_from = 'me'`)
```

example group with same timestamp

[image]

I want from this group row 3 but I get row 2 from the below query:

```
SELECT max(message_timestamp), message_id, message_text, message_conversationId
FROM MESSAGES
WHERE message_from <> 'me'
GROUP BY message_conversationId
ORDER by message_Timestamp DESC
```

What is on my mind is to do `union` from `message_id` and `timestamp` and then get the max.  If this is a good idea, how do I achieve it?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32779941/440595. Migrated here from DBA for merging.