# sqlite query with second joining

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, join, left-join

**i have table MESSAGES :**

[image]

holding messages from users conversations

**each conversation looks like this:**

[image]

**now i have QUERY I**

```
SELECT m.*
FROM 
( SELECT message_conversationId        
  FROM messages as m
  WHERE m.user_id = 1
  GROUP BY message_conversationId
) AS mc
  JOIN 
    messages AS m                          
      ON  m.message_id =        
          ( SELECT mi.message_id            
            FROM messages AS mi
            WHERE mi.message_conversationId     
                  = mc.message_conversationId
            AND mi.user_id = 1
            ORDER BY mi.message_timestamp DESC,  
                     mi.message_id DESC          
            LIMIT 1                              
          )       
  ORDER BY m.message_timestamp DESC
```

- which returns me a list of last message from each conversation
- **last is defined as last message_timestamp & last  message_id

[image]

every **row in MESSAGES TABLE holds info about one side of conversation** who sends message eg. me or other person

when i QUERY I for all conversations **i need to know second side of conversation so i need to add to this QUERY II a select / join statement**

```
LEFT JOIN 
 (  SELECT message_conversationId, message_from as message_from2, message_avatar_pic_id as message_avatar_pic_id_from2
    FROM Messages  msg_from
        -- not exactly me - but second side selected in prev query !!! --- 
    WHERE message_from <> 'me' COLLATE NOCASE 
    AND user_id == 1
    GROUP BY message_conversationId
  ) not_me ON message_conversationId = not_me.message_conversationId
```

to have this result:

[image]

> **How to combine those two queries I + II ?**

**edit:**

- i want left joining because there could be no second side of conversation - for example message was only send or received !

Comment: Please post all your queries here in text, not as pictures...

Comment: @siyual why does everyone want to experience loss of fingers by copying and pasting ? - some exercise while sitting by computer is recommended!

Comment: I didn't become a programmer because I loved exercise. Your queries aren't exactly short - the more I have to type out from a picture just to answer a question, the less I'm inclined to actually do so.

Comment: u can always use OCR :P to eliminate typing - ps. don't be angry -
I have experienced that those who always want to get everything on the plate give nothing from themselves...